# Sending a message to a user using a discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot that sends dm to a user
basically if a person types a command in a discord server like "!help"
it sends a dm to the user saying hello can you please describe your problem then it waits for the person to type his answer then it asks another question and again waits for the user to reply then the bot says done our staff will help you.
Afterwards a staff can view what the user had said to the bot.
Can you pls give me a code for this ^^^for the above thing
Can you help??I am confused pls help it would be appreciated...

Comment: It would seem that you have been heavily downvoted because you are asking people to write code for you. Stack Overflow is meant to help solve problems, not write code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't do it through DMs, i would create a private channel in the guild.
Example:

```js
    //returns if the channel id in which the help command was executed doesnt match the ID.
    if (message.channel.id !== ("Ticket creation channel ID")) {
        message.delete();
        message.author.send("You need to execute this command in #tickets!");
        return;
    }
    //Creates an embed to tell the user in the ticket channel what to do
    const ticketEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("0x7a0000")
        .setAuthor(`Hello, ${message.author.username},`);
        .setDescription("Please describe your problem so staff can help you!")

    //Creates a text channel that allows the creator of the ticket to view the channel other than "normal" members
    message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`, {
        type: "text",
        permissionOverwrites: [
            {
                id: "Default role ID",
                deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"],
            },
            {
                id: message.author.id,
                allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES"],
            },
            {
                id: "Staff role ID",
                allow: ["SEND_MESSAGES", "MANAGE_CHANNELS"]
            }
        ]
    }).then(result => {
        //Sets the slow mode to 10 seconds
        result.setRateLimitPerUser(10)
        message.channel.send(`Ticket created. Please describe your problem in <#${result.id}> so staff can help you.`)
        message.guild.channels.cache.get(result.id).send(ticketEmbed)
        //Sends "(Message author) just created a ticket in (mentioned ticket channel) and reacts with ""
        message.guild.channels.cache.get("Ticket notifier channel ID").send(`${message.author.tag} just created a ticket in <#${result.id}>`).then(r => r.react(""))
        return;
        })
```